# How to prevent kotlin.Unit object from being stripped by Proguard

Tags: proguard, kotlin

Proguard stripes `kotlin.Unit` standalone object (in Kotlin runtime library), and that causes a compilation error if you are using this type. The following rule does not help with keeping this element (perhaps because `Unit` is not a *class*, it's an *object*):

```
-keep class kotlin.Unit.** { *; }
```

We use the Unit type like this:

```
fun assert(func : Assert.() -> Unit) = Assert().apply(func)
```

Is there a workaround for this issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Progaurd rules, wildcards after the name of the class indicate nested classes. So get rid of the `.**` after `Kotlin.Unit`:

```
-keep class kotlin.Unit { *; }
```

Not directly relevant but if you use Kotlin's collections, you need to add the following Proguard rule as well:

```
-keep class kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt { *; }
```

Since Kotlin's Standard Library has its own `Collections` file and it contains top level functions and because files with top-level functions are not a direct Java class, you should use the name Kotlin conventionally uses to store this file as a Java class. From Kotlin's documentation:

> All the functions and properties declared in a file example.kt inside
>   a package org.foo.bar are put into a Java class named
>   org.foo.bar.ExampleKt.
>
> The name of the generated Java class can be changed using the @JvmName
>   annotation.

And again don't use the `.**` wildcard after the class name here.